# Can we find the Bitwise XOR of all sub-arrays of an integer array in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm

How to find the Bitwise XOR of the value of all sub arrays of array A

```
A = [1,2]
Output : 0

Explanation : 
Sub Arrays :`[1], [2], [1,2]` (XOR of all subarrays = 0)
```

Comment: It will be zero for every list with length larger than one item...

Comment: What about this case If A = [1,1,2]... I think in this case Output is 3

Comment: ah these are *subarrays* in the sence that it is a sequence, not *power sets*?

Comment: What are the sub-arrays. For `A` they could be `[],[1],[1],[2],[1,1],[1,2],[1,2],[1,1,2]`. So that would result in 0.

Comment: One: X xor X = 0. Two: how much times each array element contributes to the answer?

Comment: @itsvks: please first specify what a subarray is. (multiple different definitions are used).

Comment: For A = [1,1,2], Sub array could be [1], [1], [2], [1,1], [1,2], [1,1,2] . So Output would be 3

Comment: @itsvks: but that are **unique** subarrays... In general `[a,b,c]` results in `[],[a],[b],[c],[a,b],[a,c],[b,c],[a,b,c]`, regardless whether `a`, `b` and `c` have equalities.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : I think the subarray means the array in which the contiguousness is based on the index. So in the case of [a,b,c], Subarrays would be :     [a], [b], [c], [a,b], [b,c], [a,b,c]

Comment: In that case: think about how many times each element is going to be counted (it only depends on the length of the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, one has to decide, for each element, whether it appears in an odd or an even number of subarrays. It odd, it will appear in the xor sum, and if even it won't.

The element at position `i` will be included in `(i+1) * (n-i)` subarrays. That's because any subarray that includes `i` starts at index 0, 1, ..., i. And ends at index i, i+1, ..., n-1. Now `(i+1) * (n-1) = i(n-1) + i*i + n = (i+1)n (mod 2)` since for `x^2 = x (mod 2)` for any `x`.

So if `n` is even, no element appears in an odd number of subarrays. If `n` is odd, elements at even indices appear in an odd number of subarrays.

So:

```
def xor_all_subarrays(A):
    if len(A) % 2 == 0:
        return 0
    r = 0
    for i in xrange(0, len(A), 2):
        r ^= A[i]
    return r
```

Answer (score 1):

If with *subarrays* you mean **powersets**, you can use the fact that:

- for a list of size *n*, there are 2<sup>n</sup> lists and each element occurs in *2<sup>n</sup>/2*; and
- the bitwise xor operation is commutative and associative: `x ^ y ^ z` is equal to `z ^ x ^ y`.

Now if the list is larger than one element, every element occurs: *2<sup>n</sup>/2* times which is a **power of two**. If you xor an element two times, the result is `0`: `x ^ x = 0` for every `x`. So since it is a power of two (larger than or equal to two), the xoring of every element a power of two, the result will be `0`. In case there is *one* element, the two subarrays are `[]` and `[x]` so in that case the outcome is `x`. So a fast algorithm is:

```
def xor_subarrays_powerset(data):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return data[0]
    else:
        return 0
```

---

In the case these are **contiguousness lists** based on there index, the story is a bit different:

- here element *j* (zero indexed) will be in:

  ```
   n
  ---  
  \     
  /    min(j+1,n,i-n+1,n-j)
  ---  
  i=1
  ```

Indeed if you have a list `[1,2,3,4]`: there are the following "windows":

```
1,2,3,4
x
  x
    x
      x
1 1 1 1
x x
  x x
    x x
1 2 2 1
x x x
  x x x
1 2 2 1
x x x x
1 1 1 1
-------
4 6 6 4
```

and for a list with length 5

```
1,2,3,4,5
x
  x
    x
      x
        x
1 1 1 1 1
x x
  x x
    x x
      x x
1 2 2 2 1
x x x
  x x x
    x x x
1 2 3 2 1
x x x x
  x x x x
1 2 2 2 1
x x x x x
1 1 1 1 1
---------
5 8 9 8 5
```

So what do we note:

- for a list, the first and last element is always counted *n* times. This is logical since every moving window only passes once through these elements.
- the second and one but last element are always counted *2×(n-2)+2* times. Since all windows except the smallest and the largest pass two times;
- the third and the two but last elements are always counted *3× (n-4)+2×2+2* times;
- the fourth and the three but last elements are always counted *4×(n-6)+3×2+2×2+2*; and in general:
- the *i*-th and *n-i*-th elements (indexed zero, *i≤n/2*)  are counted *(i+1)×(n-2×i)+...*. The *...* is not important since these are **all multiples of two**. Since an element xored with itself is `0`, multiples of two do not count.

So now we only need to determine whether the elements contribute even, or odd to the total. We know that if the list has an even length, *n* is even, and thus all *(n-2×i)*, so that means that **no element will contribute** and the result is thus `0`. In case the list is odd, the first element will contribute *odd* (because *(i+1)×(n-2×i)* is odd) and the next element will contribute even, the next element will again contribute odd.

So if the list has an odd length, it means that we only need to xor over the elements positioned at `0`, `2`, `4`,... We can do this with:

```
from itertools import islice

def xor_subarrays_contiguousness(data):
    if len(data)&1:
        r = 0
        for e in islice(data,0,None,2):
            r ^= e
        return r
    else:
        return 0
```